# ¿Cómo importar un módulo en Python?

Tags: python, modulos

Hola buenas noches estoy aprendiendo a programar y quisiera saber como puedo importar un modulo en este programa

```
'''
```

Crear un programa que pregunta al usuario una cantidad de dinero a
invertir, interés anual y el número de años y muestre en pantalla el
capital obtenido en la inversión.
'''

```
cant_dinero = input("Ingrese la cantidad de dinero: ")
interes = int(input("Ingrese el interes anual: "))
años = int(input("Ingrese la cantidad de años: "))
```

**Modulo:**

```
def capitales():
    capital = (cant_dinero * (interes/100) ** años)
    ()
```

Comment: Para importar un modulo que hayas creado basta con que este en el mismo directorio y haces uso de `import nombreModulo`. Pero viendo la función que quieres usar no te va a dar el resultado deseado, debes de hacer que la función acepte los parámetros cant_dinero, interes, años

Comment: La documentación te indica como crear un módulo y como usarlo: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

Answer (score 1):

Para importar un modulo es relativamente simple basta con que escribas:

```
import modulox #modulox es solamente una referencia
```

Y veo que tienes un error en tu función, te explico, cuando defines una función debes pasarle unos parámetros, es decir:

```
def mifuncion(parametro1, parametro2, parametrox):
```

De esta formo tu función podrá ejecutarse de manera correcta, muchas veces veras que cuando llaman a la función le pasan ciertos argumentos(parámetros), pero cuando definen la función tiene parámetros pero con otros nombres, ejemplo:

```
#Definimos la función
def mifuncion(x,y):#x toma el valor de num1 he y toma el valor de num2
    suma = x + y
    #suma = 2 + 1
    return suma
    

num1 = 2
num2 = 1

#llamamos a la función
resultado_suma = mifuncion(num1,num2) #Aquí se guardará lo que retorne tu funcion, en este caso retorna suma y suma vale 3, por lo tanto resultado_suma vale 3
```

En tu caso la forma correcta de utilizar tu función es la siguiente:

```
#defino la función con sus parámetros
def capitales(cant_dinero,años,interes):
    capital = (cant_dinero * (interes/100) ** años)
    return capital

cant_dinero = input("Ingrese la cantidad de dinero: ")
interes = int(input("Ingrese el interes anual: "))
años = int(input("Ingrese la cantidad de años: "))

#Llamamos a la función
capital = capitales(cant_dinero,años,intereses)
```

Espero haberte ayudado, si tienes alguna duda puedes comentarme y no habrá problema en ayudarte